# Create back to Category button for Article View

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, category

I am looking to create a 'View all ' button on the article page.

For instance if someone views the blog layout of a category and then views an article, I am looking for a Back to blog category view button from the article itself.

I do not want to use the default, show category/link category which can be displayed at the bottom of the article as it is styled incorrectly and shows: Details: Category : link.

I have an article component override already. Whats the best way to add a back/view all article link.

Comment: but it's easy to style and tweak the current category link the way you want.

Comment: What override do I need for that ?

Comment: :: See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($params->get('link_category') == 1) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)); ?>" itemprop="genre" class="btn btn-featured article-viewcat-btn">View all <?php echo $this->item->category_title; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This was what I specifically needed, then on each category I could use the link category to show the button to all on the individual articles.

Answer (score 1):

What override do I need for that ?

Create an override for the articles layout.
Inside the html folder of the template, create a folder named "com_content", then another one "article" and copy there the article.php from `components->com_content->views->article->tmpl`.

Then inside the copied article.php file, something like the code below would work. Place it where you want the button to display:

```
<div class="view-all-btn btn button">
    <?php $catTitle = $this->escape($this->item->category_title); ?>
    <?php echo '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($this->item->catslug)) . '" itemprop="genre" title="' . $catTitle . '">View All</a>'; ?>
</div>
```

#### Update / Answer to your comment:

**Q: how do I control which categories this shows for?**
Then you could connect the appearance of the view-all button with the settings of show category and link to category. Find inside the article.php the part of the code that is printing the category title and link and modify its html output to suit your needs, but keep its checking from the backend settings, so you can control from the admin when it will be shown.

Comment: Thanks and how do I control which categories this shows for. Ie if it's uncategorised I wouldn't want the button to show

Comment: Then you could connect the appearance of the view-all button with the settings of show category and link to category. Find inside the article.php the part of the code that is printing the category title and link and modify its html output to suit your needs, but keep its checking from the backend settings, so you can control from the admin when it will be shown.

Comment: I think I saw that the code to include the category title and link was not looking at the category_link variable it's handled differently. Do you know what the correct syntax would be to check that? As it looked to be included in a different way with info.block of some sort